# How can I access the current request from my own authorization class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I need to access `Request` object from my own authorization class. Controller attribute is probably not an option and here's why.

- There are users
- There are objects
- Users can have specific permissions to objects (read/write/delete/...)
- Objects can be made public (also read/write)

Because of this system I need to write my own authorization logic and it's not a problem, I was thinking of something like so:

#### Pseudo Code

```
public class ObjectsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly AuthorizationService _auth = new AuthorizationService();

    [Route]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        var obj = new object(); // this is object that we will be working with
        // Note: This is just for demo, real object will be something like `Item`

        if (obj.IsPublic || _auth.CurrentUser.CanRead(obj))
        {
            return Ok(obj);
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

#### How I will check current user

1. Check if there is header `Token`
2. Check if there is url param `?token=`
3. Get user from token
4. Return user or null

#### Problem

Now because I need to check weather CAN this user read this `Item` (obj) AFAIK I cannot use controller attribute because I first need to get the actual item from database. What are my options? Can I access current `Request` object to extract needed values in my `AuthorizationService` class?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access with [HttpContext.Current.Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)